# Drop down menu with CSS

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I tried solving this using some tips from this site but it doesn't seem to work for me. I have a website http://apartmanimikzaton.com/paintball/index.php, and I want to create a drop down menu like from the navigation.

EDIT: I didn't add it right now, but the thing I want to get is drop down menu text on hover.

This is my navigaton:

```
<ul class="navigation">
    <li id="navigation-1"><a href="index.php?stranica=onama"> O nama </a></li>
    <li id="navigation-2"><a href="index.php?stranica=oprema"> Oprema </a></li>
    <li id="navigation-3"><a href="#"> Tereni </a>
            <ul>
                <li> <a href="#"> Lokacija 1 </a> </li> 
                <li> <a href="#"> Lokacija 2 </a> </li> 
            </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="navigation-4"><a href="index.php?stranica=galerija"> Galerija </a></li>
    <li id="navigation-5"><a href="index.php?stranica=cjenik"> Cjenik </a></li>
    <li id="navigation-6"><a href="index.php?stranica=opaintballu"> O Paintballu </a></li>
    <li id="navigation-7"><a href="index.php?stranica=teamovi"> Teamovi </a></li>
    <li id="navigation-8"><a href="#"> Webshop </a></li>
</ul>
```

And this is my css:

```
    .navigation {background: url(images/layout/navigation.jpg) no-repeat; width: 980px; height: 57px; margin: 0 0 10px 0; padding: 0;}
.navigation li, .navigation a {height: 57px; display: block;}
.navigation li {float: left; text-indent: -9999em; position: relative;}
.navigation ul ul{
  position:absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100px;          /* height of the parent list item */
  display:none;     /* hide it */
}

.navigation li:hover > ul{   /* show it when mouse is over the parent list item */
  display:block;
}
```

I'm doing something wrong so any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is the issue?

Comment: Create a jsfiddle or explain what is not working. We aren't mind readers.

Comment: I think his sub menu is not working on hover..my guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the time to analyze your code, and here's what I can help you with for now.

First of all, insert these styles into your CSS:

```
ul.navigation li ul{
   background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #000000;
   display:none;
   padding: 0;
   position: absolute;
   top: 57px;
   width: 117px;
   z-index: 6;
}
```

On the following styles:

```
.navigation li {
   float: left;
   position: relative;
   text-indent: -9999em;
   width: 100%;
}
```

The *text-indent: -9999em;* is affecting the text of the drop down menu you want to insert. I suggest you remove it. If you don't wish to display the text over your menu icons, you can simply do it like this on your link:

```
<a href="#" title="Tereni">&nbsp;</a>
```

I don't think this approach will work:

```
.navigation li:hover > ul{   /* show it when mouse is over the parent list item */
  display:block;
}
```

Try this instead and see if it works:

```
.navigation li:hover ul{
  display:block;
}
```

That should at least help you a bit, can't really tell if that's what you are intending to do. Give a response if you manage to accomplish what you wanted.

Cheers,
Artur Balestro

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. Thank you very much and sorry for not explaining in the post what I really wanted to get.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this:

```
.navigation li:hover > ul{   /* show it when mouse is over the parent list item */
   display:block;
 }
```

And Add this

```
  .navigation li:hover ul{   /* show it when mouse is over the parent list item */
         display:block;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some unnecessary styles in there that need cleaning up, but if you're wanting a quick fix:

```
.navigation > li:hover > ul,
.navigation > li:hover > ul > li,
.navigation > li:hover > ul > li > a {
    text-indent: 0;
    display: block;
    z-index: 999;
    background: #fff;
}
```